# Apache/Flask: increasing concurrent requests

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I have this Flask application running on top of Apache using mod_wsgi.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<int:a>')
def mytest(a):
    print('starting test:', a)
    import time
    time.sleep(60)
    print('ending test:', a)
    return 'done'
```

(This is a MWE.)

When the user accesses the URL `/<int>`, it performs a low-intensity task for a minute, then returns.

I then open 7 tabs, each in a different URL /1, /2, ..., /7. When I listen to what is going on (`sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`), I see the following messages:

> starting test: 1
>
> starting test: 2
>
> starting test: 3
>
> starting test: 4
>
> starting test: 5
>
> starting test: 6
>
> ending test: 1
>
> starting test: 7
>
> ...

Clearly, it only supports concurrent requests up to 6. How do I increase this limit?

I am using the default options from the Apache2 that comes with Ubuntu 18.04, and using the default options of mod_wsgi. I have already gone through `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and see no 6 limit. My .wsgi file is configured as:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app user=rpcruz group=app home=/var/www/app processes=25 restart-interval=86400 graceful-timeout=3600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: The limit was not on the server side. I was testing with Chrome which has a limit of 6 connections per hostname.